# Recursive function that saves a number provided certain conditions

Tags: python, function, recursion, definition

I'm trying to create a function in Python that, using recursion, saves a certain number if it is greater than or equal to another previously provided in input (and saved on another variable).

```
a = 6

def attempts(k):
    n = int(input("How many attempts do you want to make? "))
    if n>=k:
        return n
    else:
        print("You must make at least {} attempts to play!".format(k))
        attempts(k)

b = attempts(a)
```

The problem is that, if I don't immediately insert the "correct" number, the variable **"b"** becomes a NoneType. How can I solve this problem?
Sorry for any typos, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: `return attempts(k)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your last line of the function to:

```
return attempts(k)
```

Currently, results starting from the first recursive call (if it occurs) are thrown away, which results in `None` being returned by the outermost call.

Answer (score 1):

In the else statement, you are not returning anything, setting `b` equal to nothing. Add a return statement in the else statement and return whatever you want b to equal to if the else statement comes up.

The way your code works right now, you should add `return attempts(k)` in your else statement and remove the current last line, `attempts(k)` This will work the same, except b will have a value.

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` case you evaluate `attempts(k)` but don't return it. So it's evaluated as a `None`. Change

```
attempts(k)
```

To

```
return attempts(k)
```